# help with memory issues on adding a UIImageView to a cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, memory-management

I am adding an image to the first cell in a UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath like so:

```
if (row == 0) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"numberOneIcon.png"];
        //create a framework for the ui image view
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 37, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        //initialize the ui image view
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = image;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        [image release];
        //[imageView release];
}
```

If I uncomment out the [imageView release]; it will crash when you 'close' the app (press the home bttn) then return to the app and return to the view with the UITableView in it.

If I leave this commented it doesn't crash but am I not leaking memory here? If so is there another way to do this so as not to leak.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be releasing imageView rather than image. Change that code to the following:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        //[image release];
        [imageView release];
```

You do not own image as you did not create it with alloc, new, nor did you retain it, thus you are not supposed to be releasing it. You did alloc an instance of imageView however, so that is what you release. I strongly recommend reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Excellent, its so obvious, thanks for your quick answer mate, I def do need to read through the MM guide

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
```

for your convenience,

Comment: Thanks mate. Would it be right to say that it was best practice to release after alloc as above rather than autoRelease? I realise that either works but which works best?

Comment: the prior one(from confirmation point of view), it make you sure that you have did it.. when you wanted..